# Debian 8.10 (jessie)(OldStable) PHP7.2 (nginx) + phpMyAdmin Installation

Tags: nginx, php-7.2, debian-jessie

How do I install phpMyAdmin with php7.2 on nginx? I'm kind of new at this so it would be great if I could get some help.

I also need help installing nginx 1.14 because the one provided in Debian is very outdated at the moment.

It would be great if there was a step-by-step tutorial on installing all of them and making them work. I have a domain purchased that is connected to my host as well.

Comment: Which Debian version you need ?

Comment: Debian 8.10 (jessie) (OldStable) 64bits is the version I'm using.

Comment: you may try this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04 hope it will help you

Comment: I've already tried that link, but php7.2 doesn't have mcrypt anymore. Also, the default php version provided with phpMyAdmin is php5, not php7.2.

Comment: You can [manually install](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-7-2/) mcrypt for PHP 7.2 as pecl extension.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Is there a full tutorial for everything listed above anywhere? Or is there one you can provide?

Comment: @Antu Ok I was able to get the info.php to work. However, when I'm trying to install phpMyAdmin, it would install apache2 and php5 because it is apart of the package. Is there a way so that it  doesn't do that? I skipped the "apache2 or lighttphd" question because I was using nginx.

Comment: @jaegyuch I have not seen such tutorials. You can manually download latest phpMyAdmin and unpack it to your webserver root, but I recommend you to install and setup nginx first. See [this](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable) page for install instructions.